# Ошибка в скрипте. В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: php, xml

Скрипт должен выводить xml-файлы из каталога отсортированные по содержимому узла «categoryid» и пагинацию. Вывод файлов работает нормально, а вот количество страниц считается неверно, то есть количество страниц выводится таким, как будто учитываются вообще все файлы каталога без конкреткого «categoryid». В чём может быть проблема?

Сам скрипт:

```
$perPage = 2;

$catid = (isset($_GET['catid'])) ? (int)$_GET['catid'] : 1;
$files = scandir($fileDir);

foreach($files as $num => $file) {
    $full = $fileDir . '/' . $file;
    if(is_file($full)) {
        $articleFile = simplexml_load_file($fileDir . $file);
        if ((string)$articleFile->categoryid == $_GET['catid']) {
            if (!is_dir($fileDir . $file) && !preg_match('/^article.*\.xml$/i', $file)) continue;
        $files[$file] = filemtime($full);
        }
    }
    unset($files[$num]);
}
arsort($files);

$total = count($files);
$pages = (int) ceil($total / $perPage);

if($total > 0) {

    $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

    if($page > $pages or $page < 1)
    exit('Нет такой страницы');

    $start = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
    $out = array_slice($files, $start, $perPage);   

    foreach($out as $file => $date) {

        $articleFile = simplexml_load_file($fileDir . $file);

        if ((string)$articleFile->categoryid == $catid) {

            echo '<li><a href="' . $articleFile['id'] . '">' . $articleFile->headline . '</a></li>';
        }   


    }

    if($pages > 1) {
        echo '<div>';
        for($pr = '', $i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            echo $pr = (($i == 1 || $i == $pages || abs($i - $page) < 2) ? ($i == $page ? " $i " : '<a href="/category.php?catid=' . $catid . '?page='. $i .'">' . $i . '</a> ') : (($pr == ' ... ' || $pr == '') ? '' : ' ... '));
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }   

}
else {
    echo '<p>Нет файлов для отображения на этой странице</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, эта ошибка происходит тогда, когда вы не устанавливаете `$_GET['catid']`. Это происходит потому, что вы не используете переменную `$catid` в подсчёте общего числа файлов.
Вот эту строку:

```
if ((string)$articleFile->categoryid == $_GET['catid']) {
```

Нужно заменить вот на такую:

```
if ((string)$articleFile->categoryid == $catid) {
```

Comment: Да нет, я пробовал с переменной, тот же результат. Количество файлов он выводит как положено, но ссылок пагинатора больше чем надо. То есть он считает вывод файлов правильно, а пагинатор выводит столько ссылок страниц (1, 3, 3…), как будто учитывает все файлы каталога вообще.

Comment: Гм. А приведите в числах тогда, сколько файлов и сколько страниц он выводит.

Comment: Файлов — 4. Файлов с содержимом тега «catygorid» = 6 — 3. Пагинатор выводит 4 страницы. Вот такая беда. Помогите пожалуйста, если сообразите из моего аскетичного пояснения.